# Handling GUI with SWING with multithreading when the GUI does not update informations

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

So I have a desktop application designed using the MVC pattern inspired by [this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) (but slightly modified). What this application needs to do is to copy a list of file from a directory to another. What I would like to do is basically update my GUI after every file is copied.

First of all let me show you the code.
In my model I have this dummy method (not the real method but the logic behind it is the same):

```
public void dummyMethod(Integer k) throws InterruptedException{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
        this.firePropertyChange(DefaultController.BACKUP_DUMMY, i-1, i);
    }
}
```

In my view I have this:

```
@Override
    public void modelPropertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        // .......


        else if( evt.getPropertyName().equals( DefaultController.BACKUP_DUMMY ) ){
            System.out.println("WHAT?");
            this.dummy.setText(evt.getNewValue().toString());
        }

    }
```

As you can imagine the *WHAT?* is printed every time but the GUI is not updated until the loop has finished is thing.
That's the classic problem when you're working with SWING and its EDT and I've read on the oracle site this [article/tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) but I don't think I need to use a SwingWorker. I just need to update a single component on the GUI.

Comment: "but I don't think I need to use a SwingWorker. I just need to update a single component on the GUI."  Then you'd better read up on SwingWorkers and the EDT to learn why this is a bad decision on your part: you're avoiding the very tool that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use event dispatch thread for long running operation. You should start another thread for long running operation such as file copying. If you need to update your gui from the worker thread, you should use SwingUtilities.invokeLater or SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait methods..

as an example ;

```
final JLabel label = new JLabel();
JButton button = new JButton();
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actioPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
         Thread workerThread = new Thread() {
               public void run() {
                     //do long running job then update ui
                   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                           public void run(){
                               label.setText("Operation has finished");
                           }
                    });

               }
         }.start();    
    }
});
```

Comment: Wait. What are you doing there? Because what I need is to load a file and then notify the GUI: for each file loaded. Are you suggesting to do the loading file operation inside the GUI? That's against MVC.

Comment: That is not what was suggested. The file operation is on a separate Thread. The update of the GUI component is on the EDT, that is why you need the invokeLater() method.

Comment: It's working. I did that on the controller and it's working freakin' well. Tnx pal. BTW I had to separate the start() from the declaration, otherwise there's an error because it's void.

Comment: John V. What can I say?. I like inner classes too much. :)

Answer (score 3):

> but the GUI is not updated until the loop has finished is thing.

This indicates that all your code is running on the EDT and therefore the GUI can't repaint itself until the entire loop finishes.

> but I don't think I need to use a SwingWorker.

Why not, that is probably the easiest solution. You have your main loop run on a separate thread, and then you "publish" the results as each file is processed.

Or use the approach suggested by Gursel. The long running code is executing in a separate Thread and only the firing of the property change event is on the EDT, which means the GUI can repaint itself on the EDT.